# How deduce a generic type of variable?

Tags: rust

I declared `Lexer` trait:

```
trait Lexer<T> {}
```

Also I've implemented it for two structures:

```
impl Lexer<A> for ContainerA {}

impl Lexer<B> for ContainerB {}
```

Now I am trying to declare variable via ternary operator:

```
let lexer: Lexer<?> = if args.mode == 0 { ContainerA::new() } else { ContainerB::new() };
```

Of course, this code is wrong but... How to write correctly? To rust deduce a generic type basing on condition. Is it possible?

In short, there isn't any difference about variable type for me, I just need a some implementation of `Lexer` to use its methods.

Comment: The type of `lexer` has to be known at compile-time. It cannot depend on a runtime value like `args.mode`. 
The best you could do is use an enum type.

Comment: @Sunreef, I got, thank you! But can you explain about `enum` type, honestly, I couldn't understand how it will help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a trait object by wrapping it in a `Box` so that its size is known at compile-time.

```rust
trait Lexer {
    fn lex(&self);
}

struct ContainerA;
struct ContainerB;

impl Lexer for ContainerA {
    fn lex(&self) {
        println!("A");
    }
}

impl Lexer for ContainerB {
    fn lex(&self) {
        println!("B");
    }
}
```

Depending on your condition, you can assign different trait objects to your `lexer`.

```rust
let value = 0;
let lexer: Box<Lexer> = if value == 0 {
    Box::new(ContainerA)
} else {
    Box::new(ContainerB)
};
lexer.lex();
```

---

If you know all the types that implement your trait, you can also use an enum type.

```rust
enum Container {
    A(ContainerA),
    B(ContainerB),
}
```

Based on your condition, you can use either value of the enum while having a fixed type for your variable:

```rust
let lexer: Container = if args.mode == 0 { 
    Container::A(ContainerA::new())
} else {
    Container::B(ContainerB::new())
};
```

Comment: Thank you! But how to be if I don't know how many implementation of `Lexer` I will have? It's little weird Rust doesn't support so simple scenario.

Comment: @Шах, I edited my answer to provide a more general solution closer to what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much, `Box` is suitable for my case.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice at the beginning, my `Lexer` is parameterized by generic type, it's important. So I can't get how to use `Box` in my case.